# Otto Event Bus Subscriber of finished activity

Tags: android, otto

When I start a new activity in a fragment like this

```
    Intent launchIntent = new Intent();
    launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    launchIntent.setClassName(getBaseActivity().getPackageName(), MainActivity.class.getName());
    startActivity(launchIntent);
    getBaseActivity().finish();
```

a fragment of the old activity which is subscribing the same event I want to to catch in the new activity is called. Do I end the old activity wrong or is the fragment not ended?
I unregister in the onDestroy method of every fragment and activity.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    OttoBus.getInstance().unregister(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: where do you call `unregister` in your old activity?

Comment: i think you would have to unregister the activity before calling finish(). because u r keeping a reference of it and the object is not eligible for recycling.

Comment: I edited my question with this information.

Comment: can you post your code as well, where you call register/unregister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you called `setRetainInstance(true)` in the fragment of your "old" activity, that's why `onDestroy()` method of that fragment is not called (fragment is not destroyed by the OS, just detached from activity and kept in memory).

I would recommend you either to unregister for events in `onPause()` and register in `onStart()` or not to retain fragment in memory.

Comment: Thank you. I set the retaining to false. This solved my problem.